# autocmd setting signs is breaking syntax highlighting

Tags: vim

I currently have an autocmd for `BufAdd` that will add marks (signs) to certain lines of the loaded file. I have defined custom highlights for each sign, along the lines of:

```
highlight Custom1 ctermfg=black ctermbg=red
highlight Custom2 ctermfg=black ctermbg=green

sign define custom_sign1 text=>> texthl=Custom1
sign define custom_sign2 text=<< texthl=Custom2
```

Signs are create with:

```
sign place ID line=LINE name=custom_sign1 file=FILENAME
```

where `ID` is a unique id for the sign in the file, `LINE` is the line number for the sign, and `FILENAME` is the name of the file.

The signs all get created correctly, but it kills the syntax highlighting. I then have to do `syntax on` again, but then the custom colors for the signs don't show, at which point I have to reload the vimscript that defines those colors.

How do I make this not break syntax highlighting?

Also, this is done from an autocmd that uses the `BufAdd` and `VimEnter` events.

Edit: wrote the wrong `BufXXX` event at the end of the post - should be `BufAdd`

Update:

To duplicate my problem, source the .vim file below, and then open a new buffer that is normally syntax-highlighted. The first line will have a red `>>` sign, but the file will not be syntax highlighted. Note that it must be a *new* buffer (not already in the buffer list):

```
highlight Custom1 ctermfg=black ctermbg=red
highlight Custom2 ctermfg=black ctermbg=green

sign define custom_sign1 text=>> texthl=Custom1
sign define custom_sign2 text=<< texthl=Custom2

function! SignLine()
    execute "sign place 1 line=1 name=custom_sign1 file=" . expand("<afile>")
endfunction

autocmd!
    autocmd BufAdd * call SignLine()
augroup END
```

I created a simple file called `test.c`. After opening vim with the above .vim script as the initial file, sourcing it (with `:so %`), and then opening `test.c`, this is what I see:

[image]

After turning the syntax back on with `:syntax on`, it now looks like this (custom sign colors are now broken):

[image]

To get the custom sign colors working again, I have to re-source the vimscript *AGAIN* (`:so test.vim`), after which both the custom signs and the syntax highlighting work:

[image]

I shouldn't have to do this. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When opening your script in Vim, the syntax highlighting already gives a big clue:

[image: screenshot]

That last line isn't highlighted correctly because there's no `:augroup` command that corresponds to `augroup END`! You need to define it like that (or combine the two inner lines to `autocmd! BufAdd ...`):

```
augroup SignLine
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufAdd * call SignLine()
augroup END
```

The initial `:autocmd!` **removed all defined autocmds**, also the ones responsible for loading the syntax. That explains the broken behavior.